# Using any or none on the hash keys and values in Raku

Tags: hash, raku

I'm trying to use the `any` or `none` on the keys or values of a hash like that:

```
my %w=(a => 1, b => 2);
say %w.keys; # works
say so 'a' == %w.keys.any; # doesn't work
```

I've checked the Raku documentation's hash and map section but couldn't fix this issue. How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code dies like this:

```
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with
valid digits or '.' in '⏏a' (indicated by ⏏)
```

This happens because `==` is the numeric comparison operator, so it first tries to coerce the arguments into a number before doing the comparison.

Hash keys - at least by default - are strings, thus the `eq` operator for string comparison is needed here:

```
my %w=(a => 1, b => 2);
say so 'a' eq %w.keys.any; # True
```

Comment: `==` is more reminscent of numerical operations to help folk remember it's for numbers, `eq` is a string of letters to remind folk it compares strings. Raku has lots of ops but they follow this principle of reminding users what type they're for. `<` is *numeric* less-than. `1 < 2` is `True` and `'1' < '2'` too because Raku will coerce the strings to numbers. `lt` is *string* less-than. `'a' lt 'b'` is `True` and so is `1 lt 2` because the latter coerces to strings. What about `9 lt 10`? It's `False` because the string `'9'` is considered *greater* than `'10'` in terms of string sort order.

Comment: Note that for performance reason, you'd probably better off using the `(elem)` set operator: `say "a" (elem) %h.keys`.  This will short-circuit as soon as a key matching `"a"` has been encountered (without actually creating a `Set`).  And possibly for readability as well  :-)

Answer (score 2):

use `cmp` operator when compares with string:

```
say so 'a' cmp %w.keys.any;
```

Comment: `cmp` is a bit different.  `==` does a number comparison (coercing to a Numeric if necessary), `eq` does a string comparison (coercing to Str if necesssary).  Both return either `Bool::True` or `Bool::False`.  `cmp` returns `Order::Less`, `Order::Same` and `Order::More`, but it is multi'd to allow different logic based on the types passed.

Comment: Hi @chenyf. Your answer produces `True` when it should say `False`. The prior comment explains why. For example, `say so 'FALSE' cmp 'TRUE'` returns `True` instead of `False`. .oO ( The [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) of difference is the difference between `True` and `False` )